# How do I set up GCC Compiler to Save Executables to a Subfolder?

Tags: c++, g++, settings, executable

I do a LOT of programming in my C++ class, and I have about 60 .cpp, .o, and .exe files all piled together in one folder.  Is there any way that I can tell the compiler to save the executable file to a different directory? Like add a value --output C:/C++/Executables/ instead of C:/C++/?

Thanks in advance!
Gage Henry

PS: G++ Compiler, Running Code::Blocks

Comment: Do you have a makefile for your project? Can you show what it has?

Comment: ^sure thing... adding now

Comment: err :) where be your Makefile?

Comment: well wait a second... I mean to add the compiler option to the settings, not for just one project.  Man I was so tired last night I fell asleep before I added it.

Comment: The idea behind showing it to you in a Makefile was to make you understood the underlying concept. But I'll put up a CodeBlocks:: answer for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set it up in Code::Blocks

1. Load up the project file.
2. From the Projects Menu select `Properties...` Menu item
3. Click on the `Build targets` tab
4. If you have a build target skip to step 6.
5. Add a build target

   5.1. Click on the `Add` button
   5.2. Enter a name for your build target
6. Select your `Build target` in the left column.
7. Click on the *folder button* to the right of the `Execution working directory` text box
8. Create a folder for your test target and there you go
9. Do the same for `Objects output dir:`

Answer (score 2):

The corresponding compiler option is -o

Comment: hehe a singularly limited answer :)

Comment: Yes okay, but can I add that in the settings for Code::Blocks?

Comment: I do not know Code::Blocks, but I think you can set it per target at 'Output filename' and 'Objects output dir': http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Creating_a_new_project#Adding_a_new_build_target

Comment: **EDIT** okay just tried the option, and the executable wasn't saved to the subdirectory :/